# CubeJS PostgresDriver fails authentication but it works in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, cube.js

I can connect to my database just fine by entering `psql -U <db_user> -W -h localhost -p <db_port> -d <db_name>`. However, when I set up that same connection in a Cubejs backend, queries like `http://localhost:4000/cubejs-api/v1/load?query=...` return `{"error": "Error: password authentication failed for user \"<db_user>\""}`.

1. The database is actually connected via SSH tunnel. I've connected a truly local db to Cubejs before, so I suspect this might be causing trouble.
2. I attempt the connection like so

```js
new PostgresDriver({
    database: "<db_name>",
    host: "localhost",
    user: "<db_user>",
    password: "<db_password>"
})
```

3. The logs from the Postgres database only show stuff that looks unrelated to my connection attempts:

`2020-11-18 23:42:25 UTC::@:[6677]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time`

`2020-11-18 23:42:25 UTC::@:[6677]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.115 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65623 kB`

Comment: What is the error message from the database server's log file?

Comment: You mean the Postgres database, or Cubejs? Where does Cubejs place these logs?

Comment: The PostgreSQL database logs.

Comment: Just a bunch like these (looks like nothing gets there):

2020-11-18 23:42:25 UTC::@:[6677]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-11-18 23:42:25 UTC::@:[6677]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.115 s; sync files=1, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65623 kB

Comment: I'll edit that into the question for better formatting

Comment: There should at least be a message with "password authentication failed", but possibly with extra useful details.  Are you sure you are trying to connect to the right database instance?  Maybe you have have the wrong port, or the wrong host entirely.  (I notice you specify a port with psql, but not with node)

Comment: THAT WAS IT! I wasn't providing a port, so it was probably defaulting to `5432`, which is why my previous connections were working. Nice keen eye :D